# Unable to Access MySQL Remotely

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am using Windows Server 2016 attempting to host a PHP website via IIS that uses MySQL as the database and separately has a standalone desktop application written in VB.NET (.NET framework 4.7.2) that should also communicate with the MySQL database.

I was able to setup the website and I can hit it properly on an external network by navigating to https://mywebsite.com:8443/. I'm able to use my website which runs the PHP scripts which they in turn leverage the MySQL database on localhost:3306.

The issue comes when I attempt to access the database via the desktop application on an external network. If I connect to the machine via a VPN, setup my connection string so that the datasource is pointing to the internal IP address at port 3306, then I connect just fine. However, if I disconnect from my VPN, change the connection string so that the datasource is pointing to my public IP address, it fails to connect. What what it's worth, this is what the connection string looks like (the only thing changing is the `datasource`:

```
datasource=-public ip-;port=3306;username=dotnet;password=-password-;database=test;
```

The specific error I'm getting is:

> Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

If I change my port from `3306` to `8443` (which I don't think is right but I'm prepending it for my PHP website), I get a different error:

> Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection
> attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond
> after a period of time, or established connection failed because
> connected host has failed to respond.

I went down a rabbit hole and found that `root` did not allow for external request by default, which is why I created the `dotnet` user. From MySQL Workbench, these are the configurations for that user:

- Authentication Type: Standard
- Limit to Hosts Matching: %

I then read that the SQL server has a `bind-address` set to `127.0.0.1` by default, so I changed it to accept everything and verified by running:

```
mysqld --verbose --help
```

Scrolling until I found `bind-address` and the value it prints is `*`.

Finally, I read that I need to ensure that the firewall is setup properly. I go to Windows Firewall with Advanced Security, and see that a rule for port 3306 exists with the following properties:

- Protocol type: TCP
- Protocol number: 6 (disabled)
- Local port: Specific Ports 3306
- Remote Port: All Ports

At this point, I don't understand why it is connecting fine when VPNed to the machine, but fails when I try to connect from an external network.

Comment: Turn windows firewall off completely and try again. If it works, the problem is the firewall rules. If it does not, turn your attention to MySQL config

Comment: What config would I need to pay attention to?

Comment: So have you turned off WF and got no joy? Post the result of `netstat -a -n`

Comment: @CaiusJard - There are several. These are the ones related to 3306: `TCP    0.0.0.0:3306           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING` and `TCP    [::]:3306              [::]:0                 LISTENING`

Comment: All things point towards MySQL rejecting the connection after it audits the identity of the remote service.. I suppose one good quick test of it would be to telnet into your db server on port 3306 (you might need to install telnet by clicking start>>type "features">>choose "turn windows features on/off">>find telnet client in there and tick it) while not connected to the vpn - do you see anything that "looks MySQL-y" like what you see if you `telnet mysql-rfam-public.ebi.ac.uk 4497` (a public mysql server)..

Comment: If no success/sense from telnetting into mysql, consider shutting down MySQL, and load/run something like smtp4dev (a fake email server for developers - it's a single EXE, can be instantly configured to listen on 3306), run it on 3306, and telnet into it from your public/remote location and see if you see the greeting banner/say HELO and see what the response is. If you do get a response from this fake mail server then it proves connectivity and dialog right the way up to that port on the machine, which leads to a conclusion that MySQL would talk if it wanted to(i.e. why isn't it?)

Comment: I changed the IP address to be the user-friendly host name, but now it fails with a different error: `Failed to Connect to MySQL at -domainname-.com:3306 with user dotnet. Access denied for user 'dotnet'@'xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.` I attempted to connect via MySQL Workbench instead of my application and I'm getting the same exception.

Comment: And do you have grants for access for `'dotnet'@'xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx'` (whatever the valu of xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx is) - see some info at https://serverfault.com/questions/363122/how-does-mysql-determine-the-hostname-of-its-clients

Comment: @CaiusJard - I used the wildcard `%` instead of a specific IP address. My understanding was that it would grant access for the user to all hosts.

Comment: And there is no possibility that a different user record is being found and taking precedence? Show your users table?

Comment: @CaiusJard - I'm not sure why, but it has something to do with the port. The IT guy moved the public facing port to port 100 and it is now working. We are kind of stumped because the firewall was configured exactly the same, but I'm not spending any more time on this.